# Path Finding Using Building Maps

Tags: c#, path-finding

Hi everyone,
            I'm working on a path finding application in C# and I've run into a problem before I even start looking into coding the path finding aspect. The application will allow a user to place a marker on the map of the building then show the user the nearest exit from that position. I have the maps of the building I need but I'm not sure if I can use them straight away as jpeg images.

Would I be able to use the maps as they are or would it be better to remake them in a grid format so its all split up into squares? I'm thinking it may be easier to code the path finding aspect if the maps were made up of squares in a grid but it may take some time to remake the maps in this format.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, I do have experience in C# but path finding is a fairly new subject to me so I'm not sure of the best format for the maps to be in.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to me that the jpegs wouldn't have any bearing on whether you represent your map in code as squares in a grid.  Your jpegs should only serve as the canvas that the user sees, not as a datasource for your application to find a route.

Comment: I think it has a lot to do with your goal. If movements are going to be purely grid-based, that is the easiest way. If you intend to have a degree of randomness with walls, it gets more complicated. If you just want to follow paths, a good strategy could be to place connected nodes along the valid paths.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm might be a good place to start.

Comment: @PeterRitchie first he will need a maze though. A JPEG won't cut it, how will your program know what is a path or wall or door?

Comment: See I'm not entirely sure of the best approach, the building maps contain a lot of rooms and curves. I was initially thinking of a grid format being as the user has the freedom to place the marker anywhere they want to so the results would be random each time.

Comment: @Rogier21 It would be easier to edit the image to remove doors than to manually convert an image into coordinate data...

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone by the way. I only thought a grid format would be best because I would be able to define a black square as representing a wall etc.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - if you are able to parse the image to determine walls and boundaries, you still have to represent those boundaries in code.  Parse the image once during development, and then save the resulting boundaries in code.

Comment: What format are the maps in?

Comment: Currently the maps are just saved as plain .jpg images.

Comment: @gilly3 okay, just an optimization of what was already mentioned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you can afford some manual data processing, the best way would be to simply build a graph of the aisles and store it. You can then use simple graph search algorithms to find the nearest exit. Even spliting it into a grid is an overkill.

I've used this before to build graphs of aisles and stores in commerce buildings, and it's very useful and simple to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the response, would you be able to recommend any good tutorials or resources for me to look into it further? I'm fairly new with path finding as a whole.

Comment: @Phil_93: Finding resources is very much out of the context of StackOverflow, mostly because you can do it yourself much faster. I'd suggest, however, that by "manual data processing" he means "look at the jpeg and add nodes at intersections as points in your code".

Comment: @Magus Right, thanks for the heads up. I should have specified, I don't mean resources as in complete work for me to look at. I have no intentions of wanting my work doing for me. I just need a couple of pointers/advice.